# doctrine native sql not accepting parameter list

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to do native SQL in Doctrine. Basically I have 2 parameters:

- CANDIDATE_ID - user for who we delete entries,
- list of FILE_ID to keep

So I make

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->
    executeUpdate( "DELETE FROM FILE WHERE CANDIDATE_ID = :ID AND NOT ID IN :KEEPID",
        array(
            "ID" => $candidate->id,
            "KEEPID" => array(2) )
    );
```

But Doctrine fails:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\azk\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php on line 786
```

Is this bug in Doctrine? I'm making somewhere else select with `IN` but with QueryBuilder and it's working. Maybe someone could suggest better way of deleting entries, with QueryBuilder for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an array of IDs to a parameter. You can do this for scalar values, but even if this had a 'toString', it wouldn't be what you want.

String concatenation is one method,

`"DELETE FROM FILE WHERE CANDIDATE_ID = :ID AND NOT ID IN (". implode(",", $list_of_ids) .")"`

But this method goes straight around parameters, and therefore suffers in terms of readability, and is limited to a certain maximum line length, which can vary between databases.

Another approach is to write a function returning a table result, which takes a string of IDs as a parameter.

You could also solve this with a join to a table containing the IDs to keep.

It's a problem I've seen many times with few good answers, but it's usually caused by a misunderstanding in the way the database is modelled. This is a 'code smell' for database access.

Comment: Well I was probably mislead by Java's Hibernate, where there's convertion for parameters. Thank you

Comment: I'd still try to go with parameters where possible. It's just not possible with a `FOR IN`

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN (?)',
    array(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)),
    array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)
);
```

From [Doctrine's documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion).

Comment: If you're using parameter names: 
 array("name"=>array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) and array("name"=>\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)